# How to select multiple files in windows file explorer

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

```
// Set up the file picker.
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker openPicker =
           new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation =
               Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            openPicker.ViewMode =
                Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;


            //Filter to include a sample subset of file types.
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

            //Open the file picker.
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile file =
            await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

**I want to open Windows Explorer, select multiple images, and copy and paste to another folder.
However, with this code I am using, it is not helping me. `enter code here`**

Comment: Read this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.pickmultiplefilesasync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the multiple file method instead.

```
openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync()
```